# ffmpeg doesn't correctly work with mkv

Tags: ffmpeg, trim, mkv

Now I'm trying to trim mkv file with ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -filter_complex "[0:0]trim=start=201:duration=28,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" a.mp4
```

after processing  a.mp4 is created with length(28s), but there is problems.

1. Video is some flapped while playing.
2. Audio is continued though playing has ended beyond 28s.

So could you guys tell me what can I do?

When ffmpeg processing, it shows some errors as like this:

```
D:\Work\ffmpeg\files> ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -filter_complex "[0:0]trim=start=201:duration=28,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" a.mp4
ffmpeg version N-77883-gd7c75a5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 25.100 /  6. 25.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.1.0
  Duration: 00:35:40.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 348 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.21.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (vp8) -> trim (graph 0)
  setpts (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_mulaw (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[vp8 @ 000002859d9ae460] Discarding interframe without a prior keyframe!
[vp8 @ 000002859d9aeb00] Discarding interframe without a prior keyframe!
[vp8 @ 000002859e8eee40] Discarding interframe without a prior keyframe!
[vp8 @ 000002859e8f5460] Discarding interframe without a prior keyframe!
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      62kB time=00:00:22.27 bitrate=  22.6kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     154kB time=00:00:41.08 bitrate=  30.6kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     255kB time=00:01:02.20 bitrate=  33.6kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     340kB time=00:01:19.34 bitrate=  35.1kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     423kB time=00:01:39.31 bitrate=  34.9kbits/s
frame=   88 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=     518kB time=00:01:43.79 bitrate=  40.9kbits/
frame=  140 fps= 40 q=29.0 size=     613kB time=00:01:45.46 bitrate=  47.6kbits/
frame=  194 fps= 48 q=29.0 size=     719kB time=00:01:47.38 bitrate=  54.8kbits/

...


frame=  839 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=   10881kB time=00:34:51.52 bitrate=  42.6kbits/
frame=  839 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=   10962kB time=00:35:10.46 bitrate=  42.5kbits/
frame=  839 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=   11031kB time=00:35:25.44 bitrate=  42.5kbits/
frame=  839 fps= 14 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11266kB time=00:35:40.16 bitrate=  43.1kbits/s dup=284 drop=328 speed=34.6x
video:1083kB audio:10104kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.706855%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] frame I:4     Avg QP:15.24  size: 22651
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] frame P:305   Avg QP:19.95  size:  2626
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] frame B:530   Avg QP:25.41  size:   408
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] consecutive B-frames: 15.7%  0.0%  0.4% 83.9%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] mb I  I16..4: 15.9% 63.7% 20.4%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  1.9%  0.3%  P16..4: 22.3%  6.2%  2.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:66.5%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 16.1%  0.6%  0.1%  direct: 0.2%  skip:82.9%  L0:48.2% L1:48.5% BI: 3.4%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] 8x8 transform intra:71.1% inter:71.4%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 72.2% 78.3% 40.7% inter: 5.9% 4.0% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] i16 v,h,dc,p: 29% 30% 21% 20%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 18% 14%  5%  6%  9%  6%  9%  6%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 20% 11%  5%  5%  7%  5%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 16% 27% 11%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] ref P L0: 63.4% 21.5% 11.5%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] ref B L0: 92.6%  6.4%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] ref B L1: 96.4%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 000002859baf3300] kb/s:316.59
[aac @ 000002859baf4400] Qavg: 65377.508

D:\Work\ffmpeg\files>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 steps:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -c copy 1new.mkv

ffmpeg -y -i 1new.mkv -vf "trim=start=201:duration=28,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -af "atrim=start=201:duration=28,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" a.mp4
```

I've added the first step because I've seen this error - `Discarding interframe without a prior keyframe` - in malformed MKVs, which aren't read correctly by ffmpeg. Rewrapping usually solves that issue.

You probably should upgrade your ffmpeg, which is a fairly old build.

Comment: Thans for your response.
I've tried as you answered.
And second problem is resolved, so the audio is end as same as video.
But the first problem is remaining.
Video file is some flapped from middle of video.
It's serious problem.

Comment: I've attached mkv file on dropbox. When you send me mail account, i can share it.